# Unslider carousel "animation: 'fade'"

Tags: carousel, unslider

I'm trying to make a carousel with http://unslider.com like this:

```
$('.carousel').unslider({
  autoplay: true,
  speed: 750,
  delay: 3000,
  nav: false,
  infinite: true,
  arrows: {
    prev: '<div class="prev-btn"></div>',
    next: '<div class="next-btn"></div>'
  }
})
```

All slides became invisible when i added the option `animation: 'fade'`. I cannot figure out why.

http://codepen.io/tjeu-kayim/pen/EgYYXN

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer myself:

Add the css `.unslider-fade {height: 100%}` and the slides wil show up.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, the answer to this problem as to this date is to set a height to the unslider container. [The GitHub repo](https://github.com/idiot/unslider/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue) of the unslider project has many questions regarding this issue, but all the answers are "add a widht and height to the container".

I guess the best css selector to use would be `.unslider-fade`, and I suggest you add your own class to the slider too, so it would end up looking something like `.unslider-fade.your-class{height:###px;}`; that way you will only affect the slider with fade in your website, in case you have any other slider working with the horizontal or vertical animation (or images with some other height).

Answer (score 0):

Change your javascript a little bit:

```
$('.carousel').unslider({
  autoplay: true,
  speed: 0, //change this line(previously 750)
  delay: 3000,
  nav: false,
  infinite: true,
  arrows: {
   prev: '<div class="prev-btn"></div>',
   next: '<div class="next-btn"></div>'
 }
})
```

And add this to css:

```
.carousel ul li {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .75s; // if you want 750ms
    transition: opacity .75s; // if you want 750ms
}

.carousel ul li.unslider-active {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

And that's it, now you have "fade" effect. Enjoy!